# Is there a python type-annotation suitable for string-keyed, nested JSONish dicts?

Tags: python

I'd like to type-annotate certain data-structures in my project which are the result of decoding some JSON data.

Leaf are simple:

```
ValueType = Union[int,str,float]
```

Keys are just strings, so that's easy too:

```
str
```

But the problem is that my structures can be nested, so I'd like to do something like the following (but without the obviously failing self-reference):

```
ValueType = Union[int,str,float]
NestedDictType = Mapping[str,Union[NestedDictType,ValueType]]  # Fails!
```

I suppose I could build up something in a loop, but doing something (crazy) like this mostly defeats the point of type annotations, since the structure of NestedDictType cannot be determined statically.

```
from typing import Mapping, Type, Union

ValueType = Union[int, str, float]


def make_nested_dict_type(depth: int) -> Type:
    # Does not actually work, sorry!
    valueType = Union[make_nested_dict_type(depth - 1)] if depth else ValueType
    return Mapping[str, valueType]


NestedDictType: Type = make_nested_dict_type(4)

foo: NestedDictType = {"a": {"b": {"c": 3, "d": "four", "e": 5.6}}}
```

So how can I concisely write this kind of type-annotation?

Comment: Hey, could you give us the format of your JSON data and an example of how you would want your data structure to be ?

Comment: `mypy` doesn't (yet) supported recursive types. Otherwise, you can use a forward reference: `NestedDictType = Mapping[str,Union["NestedDictType",ValueType]]`.

Comment: I think @chepner provides the unfortunate answer - there's no point in providing this annotation, simply because there's nothing that can verify it.

Comment: Eh look at my reply. You structure your code against typed/verifiable datatypes and then when transitioning to/from json, use typedload that does runtime checks.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [typedload](https://github.com/ltworf/typedload/) a library specifically for doing this. Works with NamedTuple, Dataclasses or attrs.

```
class A(NamedTuple):
    field: str
    field_2: int
    field_3: Tuple[int, ...]

class B(NamedTuple):
    field: A

@dataclass
class C:
    field: B
```

Then I use my library to convert dicts/lists to those classes, and viceversa.

```
typedload.load(data, C)
typedload.dump(data)
```

Comment: Without at least a link to the library, this doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that as of Python 3.7, this is not 100% practical:

The typing system can define a recursive type-structure (using string forward-references), however, MyPy and PyCharm deals with the recursive portions of a type as if they are **Any**.

The closest I was able to get was to manually expand the recursive type to a number of levels. Here's an example that's partially successful.

```
import datetime
from typing import Mapping, Union, Any

# Recursive structure has been manually expanded to 3 levels, with the forward ref removed.
NestedDictType = Mapping[str,Union[int,str,float,Mapping[str,Union[int,str,float,Mapping[str,Union[int,str,float,Any]]]]]]


# MyPy correctly determines that this is valid
foo: NestedDictType = {"a": {"b": {"c": 3, "d": "four", "e": datetime.date.today()}}}

# MyPy correctly determines that this is bogus
bar: NestedDictType = {"a": datetime.date.today()}

# MyPy cannot detect the error because it's > 3 depth
baz: NestedDictType = {"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":datetime.date.today()}}}}
```